# How to nest a sequence of layered steps?

Tags: clojure, lisp, edn

Not really sure what to call this, what I mean is I have a list of steps e.g.

```clj
[{:id 1 :layer :foo}
 {:id 2 :layer :foo/bar}
 {:id 3 :layer :foo}
 {:id 4 :layer :bar/baz}
 {:id 5 :layer :foo/bar}
 {:id 6 :layer :foo/baz}
 {:id 7 :layer :foo/baz}
 {:id 8 :layer :foo/baz}
 {:id 9 :layer :foo/baz}
 {:id 10 :layer :foo}]
```

And I want to write a function that would return a nested sequence like so:

```clj
[{:layer :foo :steps [1 {:layer :foo/bar :steps [2]} 3]}
 {:layer :bar :steps [{:layer :bar/baz :steps [4]}]}
 {:layer :foo :steps [{:layer :foo/bar :steps [5]}
                      {:layer :foo/baz :steps [6 7 8 9]}
                      10]}]
```

Conceptually I understand how zippers might be used for something like this, but I don't know how to use them well enough to apply even after research. This is similar to what I'd use postwalk for, except there's a lot of next step previous step stuff regarding when to go up or down a layer.

Is there any alternative that's more idiomatic than a big ugly `loop`?

Comment: I assume the order of `:steps` mattes. But does the order of the items in the resulting top-level vector matter? If having multiple layers in the input with the same ID is possible, please provide an example of what you expect when such layers go next to each other and also when they have some other layers between them.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Yes the order matters, yes in the top-level vector as well, edited my example. I hope this is more clear. The steps plot a course through multiple layers, I'm trying to get a complementary nesting of the flat steps through the layers with step IDs used for reference

Comment: Conceptually the returned value is also a `:steps` list in a hypothetical base layer

Comment: On a 2s skim, this strikes me as a weird use of namespaced keywords. Maybe the layers should be vectors of keywords instead?

Comment: @Harold Yeah it doesn't really match how clojure reads namespaced keywords, i.e. `(= (name :foo/bar/baz) "bar/baz")`, but that's easy enough to solve convert in place while doing the nesting. I'm mostly using keywords in this way for semantics. I got that far, I'm just not sure how to actually do the nesting even given a function e.g. `(= (layers :foo/bar/baz) [:foo :foo/bar :foo/bar/baz])`

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your layers into vectors of keywords...

```
[{:id 1 :layer [:foo]}
 {:id 2 :layer [:foo :bar]}
 {:id 3 :layer [:foo]}
 {:id 4 :layer [:bar :baz]}
 {:id 5 :layer [:foo :bar]}
 {:id 6 :layer [:foo :baz]}
 {:id 7 :layer [:foo :baz]}
 {:id 8 :layer [:foo :baz]}
 {:id 9 :layer [:foo :baz]}
 {:id 10 :layer [:foo]}]
```

... you could use something like this:

```
(defn solution
  ([object] (solution object 0 []))
  ([object level path-so-far]
   (into [] (mapcat (fn [part]
                      (if-let [delimiter (-> part first :layer (nth level nil))]
                        [{:layer (conj path-so-far delimiter)
                          :steps (solution part
                                           (inc level)
                                           (conj path-so-far delimiter))}]
                        (mapv :id part))))
         (partition-by (comp #(nth % level nil) :layer) object))))
```

With this result:

```
(solution [{:id 1 :layer [:foo]}
           {:id 2 :layer [:foo :bar]}
           {:id 3 :layer [:foo]}
           {:id 4 :layer [:bar :baz]}
           {:id 5 :layer [:foo :bar]}
           {:id 6 :layer [:foo :baz]}
           {:id 7 :layer [:foo :baz]}
           {:id 8 :layer [:foo :baz]}
           {:id 9 :layer [:foo :baz]}
           {:id 10 :layer [:foo]}])
=>
[{:layer [:foo], :steps [1 {:layer [:foo :bar], :steps [2]} 3]}
 {:layer [:bar], :steps [{:layer [:bar :baz], :steps [4]}]}
 {:layer [:foo], :steps [{:layer [:foo :bar], :steps [5]} {:layer [:foo :baz], :steps [6 7 8 9]} 10]}]
```